# No-simultaneous-events assumption of the Poisson process

Tags: assumptions, poisson-process

I am checking the description of [Poisson process from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process).
The Poisson process is based on four assumptions, but I am not clear this:

> No counted occurrences are simultaneous.

Can you explain this more?

Comment: It means that in your Stochastic model for whatever you're analysing, you assume that it cannot occur twice at the same time (for a temporal Poisson process).  So if you were modelling arrivals to a queue, you are assuming that two people won't arrive at the same time.  For a more technically precise explanation, see here: http://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter2/2.12.1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means two or more events do not occur at the same time. Say, we are interested in the number of goals scored in a match. Then the goals are assumed to be scored at different time points. This seems to be very reasonable. But think about the number of accidents in a city in a day. It may happen that there were two accidents at exactly the same time at different places. But for the Poisson process, our assumption is that only one accident can occur at a time point. No counted accidents are simultaneous. Two different accidents are assumed to occur at two different time points.

Comment: Aren't two events never going to happen at exactly the same time almost surely because time is continuous, ie. at least some extremely small difference will almost always be there between two events and any apparent synchrony is only due to the time granularity we have to introduce due to our imperfect measurement?

Comment: Well, that's why I have put the example of accidents count. So, you see you can not ignore the chance of occurring two accidents in our study area at exactly the same time (very rare though). But for the ease of further calculation the assumption the OP pointed is made.

Comment: A better example is to think about a process of births modelled as a stochastic process. No simultaneous occurences imply that we do not take into account twin births!

Comment: Good one! Or at least the twins haven't come out at the same time! So the assumption sounds quite reasonable.

Comment: Which distribution is used when events *can be* simultaneous?